# Datomic Pro bin/run no suitable driver found

Tags: clojure, datomic

I'm trying to run Datomic Pro with the following command:

```
./bin/run -m datomic.peer-server -h localhost -p 8998 -a myaccesskey,mysecret -d demo,"datomic:sql://jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/datomic?user=datomic&password=datomic"
```

But every time I run that command it throws:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver
```

Any thoughts?

ps: I've already added mysql connector jar to ./lib.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gabriel,

You need to provide a database name to the peer-server command.  You'll want to start a datomic peer against your running transactor and create the database first.  For this example I created the "test" db.

```
(require '[datomic.api :as d])
(def uri "datomic:sql://test?jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/datomic?user=datomic&password=datomic")
(d/create-database uri)
```

That create DB should return true.  Once created your URI string will look like:

```
./bin/run -m datomic.peer-server -h localhost -p 8998 -a myaccesskey,mysecret -d demo,"datomic:sql://test?jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/datomic?user=datomic&password=datomic"
```

Cheers,
Jaret